# Defining declared member function inside struct

Tags: c++, class, struct, function-definition, member-functions

```
struct a_t {
  struct not_yet_known_t;
  struct b_t {
    void f(not_yet_known_t* m);
  };
  struct c_t {
    b_t b;
    //...
  };
  struct not_yet_known_t {
    c_t c;
    //...
  };

  // ERROR HERE
  void b_t::f(not_yet_known_t* m) {
    // code comes here
  }
};

int main() {
  a_t::not_yet_known_t m;
  a_t::b_t b;
  b.f(&m);
}
```

Is it possible to define `a_t::b_t::f` inside `a_t::` scope some way? Or if we could access global scope inside `a_t::` but not actually pasting the code outside `a_t::` scope?

Error I get:

```
main.cpp:16:13: error: non-friend class member 'f' cannot have a qualified name
  void b_t::f(not_yet_known_t* m) {
       ~~~~~^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct a_t {
  struct not_yet_known_t;
  struct b_t {
    void f(not_yet_known_t* m){ _b_t_f(this, m); }
  };
  struct c_t {
    b_t b;
    //...
  };
  struct not_yet_known_t {
    c_t c;
    //...
  };

  static void _b_t_f(b_t* b, not_yet_known_t* m) {
    // code comes here
  }
};
```

Instead of declaring a_t::b_t::f you can define it to call another function then define that function in outside of a_t::b_t.

You can use this way if you don't want to go outside of `struct a_t`. I suggest naming that function `_b_t_f` something like struct name + function name to be sure it will never collide with other things.

Answer (score 2):

The function

```
void f(not_yet_known_t* m);
```

is not a member of the structure struct a_t and not its friend function. So it may not be defined within the structure struct a_t.

You can define it outside the structure declaration as for example

```
struct a_t {
  struct not_yet_known_t;
  struct b_t {
    void f(not_yet_known_t* m);
  };
  struct c_t {
    b_t b;
    //...
  };
  struct not_yet_known_t {
    c_t c;
    //...
  };
};


  void a_t::b_t::f(a_t::not_yet_known_t* m) {
    // code comes here
  }
```

You may define within a class either its own member functions or its friend functions that are not members of other classes.

Comment: I know its possible to declare in global scope, but in my case its not possible to put it to global scope. The code I am showing is just an example code.

Comment: @pesuww If you have such a problem you should consider a possibility to redesign your classes. Usually this just means that you are doing something wrong.